# Translate FormHelper Months CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

FormHelper of **CakePHP 2.0.6** (*in 1.3 works perfectly*), not accept app/Locale/pt_br/LC_MESSAGES/default.po.
When I open file for check, I see this:

```
__d('cake', 'January');
```

How I can override "__d" and/or 'cake' plugin.
Because, when I change _*d() to _*(), works fine, but I think this not a perfect solution.

```
__('January');
```

Thanks.
*Sorry for my english, I'm Brazilian*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all those translations into `app/Locale/pt_br/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po`. The `d` in `__d` switches to another *domain*, and those domains are simply different files in the LC_MESSAGES directory.

Comment: Doesn't work my friend. Now I have: app/Locale/pt_br/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po, and back __d to FormHelper.... so: all in english again. What did I do wrong?

Comment: No my friend, really doesn't work. I try everthing, but nothing work.

Comment: it is still the correct answer. you probably didnt apply the correct config setting for cake to know the currently active language. also - using the i18n extract shell this would be handled by cake automatically.

Comment: Now it worked, but was a doubt: the translations that insert in the file no longer work (translations of my application, not the cakephp). Should I keep two files? cake.po and default.po?

Answer (score 5):

I searched for like an hour for a solution because I'm having the same problem. Here is how I did it:

1. Create `cake.po` translation file in `/app/Locale/[your language key]/LC_MESSAGES/`
2. Copy the following in this file and translate the `msgstr` entries to your language:

   ```
   msgid "January"
   msgstr "Januar"

   msgid "February"
   msgstr "Februar"

   msgid "March"
   msgstr "März"

   msgid "April"
   msgstr "April"

   msgid "May"
   msgstr "Mai"

   msgid "June"
   msgstr "Juni"

   msgid "July"
   msgstr "Juli"

   msgid "August"
   msgstr "August"

   msgid "September"
   msgstr "September"

   msgid "October"
   msgstr "Oktober"

   msgid "November"
   msgstr "November"

   msgid "December"
   msgstr "Dezember"
   ```
3. Add `Configure::write('Config.language', '[your language key (same as the folder created above)]');` to your bootstrap or set it elsewhere.
4. Tada!

**Explanation:** The month names in the CakePHP helper are translated via the `cake` domain: `__d('cake', 'January')` ([see file on github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L2513)) so normal translation in the `default.po` file won't work.

Comment: Yes, I do that, but doesnt work. The only way is alter the original FormHelper.php. Anyway, thank you so much.

Comment: Just curious: did you try with a three-character locale codes conform to the ISO 639-2 standard and not with 'pt_br'? The above works perfectly in my app so I cannot believe its not working :)

Comment: So, I try this, but nothing happend. Look here for details: https://gist.github.com/3222238 (I use language 'cpp' - just for test - I can right?)

Comment: You did not name the translation file `cake.po` as stated in your code. It has to be `cake.po` NOT `default.po` to work with the built in translations, because the translation domain is another. See point 1 in my answer above. cpp seems to be the right code.

Comment: Also watch out that the `.po` file isn't a PHP file! I see php tags around all of your code sample.

Comment: About php tags,I just use in Gist dont worry. I'll test with cake.po and answer you. Wait a moment.

Comment: I rename my file default.po to cake.po and doesn't work. I dont know why. /.../app/Locale/pt-br/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po

Comment: Now works my friend. I use incorrect folder for 'cake.po'. Is pt_br not pt-br (on core.php its incorrect too). Anyway, thanks.